# Mapbox in Android - Black color around GEOTiff raster layers

Tags: mapbox, gdal, mapbox-android

### Goal

I need to add some aeronautical layers taken from FAA to the map. The layers are provided as GeoTIFF files.

### Steps

1. Downloaded a GeoTiff file from [FAA](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/vfr/) website.
2. Using [QGis](https://qgis.org/en/site/) app clipped the legend from the file. Actually the issue occurs without this step as well.
3. Reprojected it to `EPSG:3857` using GDAL command `gdalwarp -q -t_srs EPSG:3857 -dstalpha -of vrt Albuquerque\ SEC\ 104-cut.tif /vsistdout/ | gdal_translate -co compress=lzw  /vsistdin/ Albuquerque\ SEC\ 104-north-up-cut.tif`. Otherwise I got `Error creating Mapnik Datasource: Invalid raster: Invalid rotation value in geotransform array` when uploading to Mapbox.
4. Created a Tileset by uploading GeoTIFFs to [Mapbox](https://studio.mapbox.com/tilesets/).
5. Created a new style in the [Mapbox Studio](https://studio.mapbox.com/).
6. Added the tilesets as layers.

### Mapbox Studio Result

The map is showing well in **Mapbox Studio**:

[image: mapbox]

### Android Result

However in Android app this style shows with some black borders of random width depending on zoom level and camera position. 
Here is how it looks in android:

[image: Android]
[image: Android Screenshot]

I tried it on Pixel 3a (Android 10), Nexus 5x (Android 8.1) and Android emulator (Android 10). I have good internet connection and gave it enough time so the tiles are loaded.

The source code where the map is embedded is official [Demo app](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo). I just replaced token and style URL:

```
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
    DefaultStyleActivity.this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
      mapboxMap.setStyle("mapbox://styles/rustamg/ck8se724l23bh1io2b1hnbqls");
  }
});
```

Here is GDALInfo for the GEOTiff I uploaded:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /Users/me/Desktop/Dev/Albuquerque SEC 104-north-up-cut.tif
Size is 16104, 11408
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (-12154316.342745549976826,4340308.343459489755332)
Pixel Size = (51.194510520863538,-51.194510520863538)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2019:09:03 09:02:22
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Adobe Photoshop CC (Windows)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=300
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=300
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-12154316.343, 4340308.343) (109d11' 2.69"W, 36d17'16.43"N)
Lower Left  (-12154316.343, 3756281.367) (109d11' 2.69"W, 31d56'47.16"N)
Upper Right (-11329879.945, 4340308.343) (101d46'40.96"W, 36d17'16.43"N)
Lower Right (-11329879.945, 3756281.367) (101d46'40.96"W, 31d56'47.16"N)
Center      (-11742098.144, 4048294.855) (105d28'51.82"W, 34d 8'42.17"N)
Band 1 Block=16104x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
  Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
    0: 255,255,255,255
    1: 255,255,0,255
    2: 255,0,255,255
    3: 255,0,0,255
    4: 0,255,255,255
    5: 0,255,0,255
    6: 0,0,255,255
    7: 0,0,0,255
    8: 252,252,254,255
    9: 255,255,1,255
   10: 252,236,170,255
   11: 248,228,166,255
   12: 228,200,154,255
   13: 154,81,86,255
   14: 120,103,105,255
   15: 221,135,154,255
   16: 166,87,106,255
   17: 107,86,91,255
   18: 172,104,124,255
   19: 79,9,35,255
   20: 141,59,88,255
   21: 126,12,61,255
   22: 229,107,161,255
   23: 200,150,173,255
   24: 234,178,204,255
   25: 100,8,53,255
   26: 200,81,137,255
   27: 146,68,105,255
   28: 136,38,88,255
   29: 98,29,64,255
   30: 190,113,151,255
   31: 119,44,83,255
   32: 214,182,199,255
   33: 177,144,163,255
   34: 116,13,75,255
   35: 33,8,25,255
   36: 143,116,141,255
   37: 232,216,232,255
   38: 248,232,248,255
   39: 77,26,86,255
   40: 75,69,104,255
   41: 105,103,125,255
   42: 40,36,105,255
   43: 8,8,24,255
   44: 232,232,248,255
   45: 120,120,122,255
   46: 8,14,85,255
   47: 203,204,216,255
   48: 60,62,80,255
   49: 8,22,115,255
   50: 86,88,104,255
   51: 180,184,201,255
   52: 8,54,179,255
   53: 8,40,120,255
   54: 28,56,120,255
   55: 8,40,104,255
   56: 143,152,171,255
   57: 8,54,136,255
   58: 37,47,65,255
   59: 184,201,232,255
   60: 25,72,152,255
   61: 202,214,233,255
   62: 31,56,95,255
   63: 8,84,182,255
   64: 8,72,158,255
   65: 8,56,120,255
   66: 9,42,86,255
   67: 25,72,136,255
   68: 37,88,152,255
   69: 51,75,104,255
   70: 11,100,202,255
   71: 8,23,40,255
   72: 27,72,120,255
   73: 8,56,104,255
   74: 44,88,133,255
   75: 184,198,212,255
   76: 80,84,88,255
   77: 8,72,133,255
   78: 22,104,178,255
   79: 71,121,168,255
   80: 91,134,173,255
   81: 43,121,184,255
   82: 80,113,140,255
   83: 8,88,152,255
   84: 24,88,136,255
   85: 53,104,143,255
   86: 8,88,136,255
   87: 22,104,149,255
   88: 114,144,162,255
   89: 139,172,191,255
   90: 104,124,134,255
   91: 146,205,232,255
   92: 136,197,216,255
   93: 134,184,201,255
   94: 153,200,216,255
   95: 135,216,232,255
   96: 85,105,109,255
   97: 213,233,236,255
   98: 152,195,200,255
   99: 167,216,221,255
  100: 181,232,237,255
  101: 151,233,237,255
  102: 8,24,24,255
  103: 230,248,248,255
  104: 182,183,183,255
  105: 184,217,216,255
  106: 120,136,134,255
  107: 24,40,37,255
  108: 174,207,200,255
  109: 143,147,145,255
  110: 225,248,232,255
  111: 103,120,104,255
  112: 8,24,8,255
  113: 87,104,86,255
  114: 212,232,210,255
  115: 181,200,175,255
  116: 163,171,158,255
  117: 229,248,216,255
  118: 198,216,184,255
  119: 147,172,126,255
  120: 231,248,200,255
  121: 200,216,168,255
  122: 216,232,178,255
  123: 200,216,151,255
  124: 232,248,184,255
  125: 212,232,146,255
  126: 232,248,167,255
  127: 189,207,105,255
  128: 199,200,152,255
  129: 248,248,71,255
  130: 24,24,8,255
  131: 145,144,57,255
  132: 248,248,104,255
  133: 216,216,135,255
  134: 248,248,168,255
  135: 200,200,136,255
  136: 216,216,152,255
  137: 232,232,168,255
  138: 248,248,184,255
  139: 216,216,168,255
  140: 232,232,184,255
  141: 248,248,200,255
  142: 200,200,168,255
  143: 120,120,101,255
  144: 232,232,200,255
  145: 248,248,216,255
  146: 216,216,193,255
  147: 200,200,184,255
  148: 232,232,216,255
  149: 248,248,232,255
  150: 170,168,56,255
  151: 201,194,72,255
  152: 179,174,78,255
  153: 229,223,101,255
  154: 214,205,88,255
  155: 196,189,104,255
  156: 232,218,133,255
  157: 246,233,151,255
  158: 42,40,29,255
  159: 148,136,82,255
  160: 200,184,120,255
  161: 216,200,136,255
  162: 232,216,152,255
  163: 248,232,168,255
  164: 165,152,104,255
  165: 114,106,76,255
  166: 182,173,141,255
  167: 248,216,115,255
  168: 183,168,119,255
  169: 147,139,114,255
  170: 200,168,72,255
  171: 216,184,88,255
  172: 200,184,136,255
  173: 216,200,152,255
  174: 232,216,168,255
  175: 248,232,184,255
  176: 228,184,72,255
  177: 200,168,88,255
  178: 216,184,104,255
  179: 81,74,58,255
  180: 248,188,71,255
  181: 232,185,88,255
  182: 248,199,101,255
  183: 200,168,104,255
  184: 216,184,120,255
  185: 232,200,136,255
  186: 248,216,152,255
  187: 168,152,120,255
  188: 200,184,152,255
  189: 216,200,168,255
  190: 232,216,184,255
  191: 219,167,72,255
  192: 178,144,82,255
  193: 248,231,200,255
  194: 184,136,56,255
  195: 216,168,88,255
  196: 232,185,104,255
  197: 248,200,123,255
  198: 220,150,49,255
  199: 130,93,40,255
  200: 200,152,84,255
  201: 184,152,104,255
  202: 200,168,120,255
  203: 216,184,136,255
  204: 232,200,152,255
  205: 248,216,168,255
  206: 179,119,36,255
  207: 160,114,54,255
  208: 216,168,104,255
  209: 232,184,120,255
  210: 200,137,56,255
  211: 232,168,88,255
  212: 61,53,43,255
  213: 146,115,80,255
  214: 216,168,120,255
  215: 248,200,152,255
  216: 168,136,104,255
  217: 184,152,120,255
  218: 200,168,136,255
  219: 216,184,152,255
  220: 232,200,168,255
  221: 248,216,184,255
  222: 216,200,184,255
  223: 248,232,216,255
  224: 110,87,68,255
  225: 248,184,135,255
  226: 170,151,137,255
  227: 184,136,104,255
  228: 200,152,120,255
  229: 216,168,136,255
  230: 232,184,150,255
  231: 248,200,168,255
  232: 171,114,77,255
  233: 168,136,120,255
  234: 232,200,184,255
  235: 200,183,174,255
  236: 232,164,134,255
  237: 200,168,154,255
  238: 248,167,139,255
  239: 171,119,104,255
  240: 216,168,154,255
  241: 184,133,121,255
  242: 140,117,111,255
  243: 232,213,208,255
  244: 201,148,137,255
  245: 235,181,172,255
  246: 216,138,126,255
  247: 41,24,23,255
  248: 24,8,8,255
  249: 248,232,232,255
  250: 201,200,200,255
  251: 248,248,248,255
  252: 232,232,232,255
  253: 104,104,104,255
  254: 24,24,24,255
  255: 8,8,8,255
Band 2 Block=16104x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

### Question

How can I get rid of those black issues?

I'd be happy to provide more info if needed.

### Update 2020-05-06

I tried what's suggested in [troubleshooting page](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/raster-transparency-issues/#edit-the-original-image): both prepare tileset and create RasterSource within Android app. The first command `rio calc "(asarray (take a 1) (take a 2) (take a 3))" --co compress=lzw --co tiled=true --co blockxsize=256 --co blockysize=256 --name a=filename.tif filename255.tif` failed with an error:

> IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for size 1

However my tif already uses LZW compression. So I tried the second command:

```
rio edit-info --nodata 0 filename255.tif
```

and uploaded the result to Mapbox.
The result was the same except that white background of the image became black as well:
[image: No-data not working. Big]

I also tried the same steps with smaller image (409x306) as it's pointed [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native-android/issues/331#issuecomment-619841561) that Android has texture size limitation. The result is all the same:
[image: Small image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black borders should be transparent, but the raster image format Mapbox is using (JPG) does not support transparency, which is a known issue that exists in every gl-native-based SDK. This issue presents itself when you reference a style that has the raster layer built in.

As a workaround, you can follow Mapbox's troubleshooting guide on [troubleshooting raster images with black backgrounds](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/raster-transparency-issues/) to make your tileset transparent and then add the tileset as a `RasterSource` within your Android application to display the raster tile as expected.

Please take a look at the following example as a reference for adding a RasterSource:

- [Add a WMS Source](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/add-a-wms-source/)

Instead of calling the rasterSource using "mapbox://username.tilesetID", you need to call it similarly to the Add a WMS Source example. The code below will resolve your issue:

`style.addSource(RasterSource( "albuquerque-source", TileSet( "tileset", "https://api.mapbox.com/v4/<username.tilesetID>/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=<your_access_token>" ), 256 ))`

Comment: Thanks for the info and links @invaderzizim. I have tried this and updated the question with results (the same). Could you please have a look?

Comment: @RustamG, are you calling the tileset as a rasterSource, rather than referencing the style with the tileset already added as a layer? If I add the style with the tileset already in it as a layer I experience the same issue. As mentioned above, the raster tile needs to be added as a raster source.

Comment: @RustamG slight correction: I do see that the image becomes black in certain areas if you zoom in very closely, but my rasterSource does not appear as yours does. Do you mind sharing the file you used to create your raster source?

Comment: Yep, I tried to add the tileset as a RasterSource. 
Here is one of the Tiff I uploaded to MapBox as a tileset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16D8v-K9GK_3zk_zgj4uuNTzNZ2-hJYTU/view?usp=sharing
Thanks for helping. I really appreciate your attention.

Comment: @RustamG you're most welcome. Hmm...what happens when you try to add the original file (directly from the link you sent without making any changes) to Mapbox and add that as a rasterSource? When I do that, I get a map with a raster with no black background.

Comment: The issue is there even if I add it as a RasterSource. Glad to hear that you don't have issues with this. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong. I created a simple repo demonstrating the issue: https://github.com/RustamG/mapbox-raster-layer-issue. Could you please have a look?

Comment: Instead of calling it with "mapbox://username.tilesetID" you need to call it similarly to the Add a WMS Source example I linked in my response https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/add-a-wms-source/. The code below will resolve your issue.

`style.addSource(RasterSource(
                        "albuquerque-source",
                        TileSet(
                            "tileset",
                            "https://api.mapbox.com/v4/<username.tilesetID>/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=<your_access_token>"
                        ), 256
                    ))`

Comment: My apologies for the confusion - while that second link's examples of using "mapbox://username.tilesetID" works for adding rasterSources, it does not account for the black padding you're trying to remove, while the method in the Add a WMS source example does.