# Mapbox - Download raster tiles to display offline

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-ios

My app (iOS/Android) needs to download raster tiles for using offline. Due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61141793/mapbox-in-android-black-color-around-geotiff-raster-layers) I cannot add raster tiles to a Style through Mapbox Studio. What are the options to be able to download my raster tiles and display them even offline?

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox Studio does not provide a way to download raster tiles -- that is, if you uploaded imagery to the [tilesets page](https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/reference/tilesets/#manage-tilesets) in Mapbox Studio via the [Uploads API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#uploads) to create a raster tileset, this tileset is not available for download. You may have raster tiles already downloaded from another source, however, in which case this part of the answer is not applicable to your use case.

Storing raster tiles and displaying them offline is an example of sideloading, a workflow which Mapbox GL Native (the C++ library powering the Mapbox Maps SDKs for Android and iOS) no longer officially supports (as noted [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/16346#issuecomment-611180284)). However, if you are able to create a local custom raster style using your raster tiles, you can follow [this Android example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/16346#issuecomment-611180284) and [this iOS example](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/raster-styles/) to use said local style in your implementation.